# Maven. Put .DLL in the root of JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar

How I can include  native `.dll` file in root of JAR using Maven?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you already have your .dll file just store it in your project's `src/main/resources` directory and Maven will put it in the target jar's root directory.